# parsing nested json alasql and export to excel

Tags: javascript, xlsx, alasql

I have been trying to export multiple nested json into worksheets using alasql, but the problem is alasql is unable to parse nested json.

```
var data1= [{'a':1,'b':[{'c':3,'d':4},{'c':5,'d':6}],'e':7,'f':8}];
var data2= [{'g':1,'h':{'i':3,'j':4,'k':5},'l':7,'m':8}];
var opts = [{sheetid:'One',header:true},{sheetid:'Two',header:false}]
var res = alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("Test.xls",?) FROM ?',
                 [opts,[data1,data2]]);
```

How do i export these json in xlsx

Comment: What should be the expected output for this example?